# Determine the runtime of the function:

Tags: java, runtime

```
public static void p2(int N) { 
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1) { 
    for (int j = 1; j < N; j = j * 2) {  
        System.out.println("hi !"); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Can you help me to determine the runtime of this function?

I have tried to find some pattern for different inputs of N. I calculated costs for inputs up to 5 (println was used for this purposes):

N: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

C(N): 0, 0, 2, 6, 8, 15

Where C(N) is the cost function.

However, I don't know how to proceed next! The answer is Θ(N log(N))

Answer (score 4):

The inner loop is going to execute `lg n` times.
You can understand this by looking at how many times will you divide `N` by 2 to get 1? (i.e. how many times is the inner loop going to execute?) The answer to this is `lg n`.
And the outer loop will be running `N` times. So for each iteration of `i` , the inner loop will run `lg n` times. Which means that the nested loop will run exactly `n(lgn)` times which is the time complexity of this question.

Comment: Thank you! I must have written this. I know the intuition. However, I would like to get more math. rigorous answer.

Comment: You should find first that it is O(N log(N)) and Ω(N log(N)) using that same explanation for both to conclude that the complexity is Θ(N log(N)). Check: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-big-oh-big-omega-and-big-theta-notations